# Rails changed column case when doing query with date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails and trying to get distinct dates from my Table **Echeancier** and column **ech_dtDate**.

My query:

```
 @dates = Echeancier.where('ech_dtDate BETWEEN ? AND ?',@dateCurrent.beginning_of_month,@dateCurrent.end_of_month).uniq.pluck(:ech_dtDate)
```

I have the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "ech_dtdate" does not exist LINE 1: ...heanciers"."ech_dtDate" FROM "echeanciers" WHERE (ech_dtDate... ^ HINT: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "echeanciers.ech_dtDate". : SELECT DISTINCT "echeanciers"."ech_dtDate" FROM "echeanciers" WHERE (ech_dtDate BETWEEN '2018-10-31 23:00:00.000000' AND '2018-11-30 22:59:59.999999')
```

Why Rails changed column ech_dtDate to ech_dtdate? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally with respect to *rails conventions*, the **column names** should be in l*owercase and snake_case*. Probably you are getting the error as the column name `ech_dtDate` is conflicting with naming conventions that rails follows. You have two options.

**Option #1:**

Try renaming the column name with the migration by following the below steps.

1) Generate a migration file

```
rails g migration FixColumnName
```

2) Open the file and add

```
rename_column :echeanciers, :ech_dtDate, :ech_dtdate
```

and save the file.

3) Run `rake db:migrate` in the terminal.

**Option #2:**

Add the below line in `Echeancier` model.

```
alias_attribute :ech_dtdate, :ech_dtDate
```

and you are good to go.